# ParcelableArraylist may produce nullpointerexception in fragment

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to pass `ArrayList<Palatte_Model>` from one Activity to another fragment. I am using `ParcelableArraylist`. Here I attached my code

```
public class Palette_Model  implements Parcelable{

    public String data_format_value;
    public int data_format_id;

    public Palette_Model(String data_format_value, int data_format_id) {
        this.data_format_value = data_format_value;
        this.data_format_id = data_format_id;

    }
    public String getData_format_value() {
        return data_format_value;
    }

    public void setData_format_value(String data_format_value) {
        this.data_format_value = data_format_value;
    }

    public int getData_format_id() {
        return data_format_id;
    }

    public void setData_format_id(int data_format_id) {
        this.data_format_id = data_format_id;
    }


    protected Palette_Model(Parcel in) {
        data_format_value = in.readString();
        data_format_id = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return this.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(data_format_value);
        dest.writeInt(data_format_id);

    }

    public void readfromParcel(Parcel source){
        data_format_id = source.readInt();
        data_format_value = source.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Palette_Model> CREATOR = new Creator<Palette_Model>() {
        @Override
        public Palette_Model createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Palette_Model(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Palette_Model[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Palette_Model[size];
        }
    };
}
```

here i attached my activity class code. to send arraylist to fragment

```
Platte_fragment dFragment = new Platte_fragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist",  strQuestion);
                dFragment.setArguments(bundle);
              //  dFragment.show(fragmentManager, "array list");
                FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fts.replace(R.id.questContFragId, dFragment);
                fts.addToBackStack(dFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
                fts.commit();
```

here I mentioned my fragment class code:
I fetch the `ArrayList` from `Activity`. it shows a null value

```
ArrayList<Palette_Model> strQuestion ;

 strQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
         try {
             Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
             strQuestion =  bundle.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");

         }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e("er",e.getMessage());
         }
```

The shown method may produce `NullpointerException`.

Comment: please share  logcat

Comment: please add exception you are getting in logcat

Comment: my arraylist value is empty. i print the array list is show empty value

Comment: Try return zero in  `describeContents()`

 `@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }`

Comment: i tried bro, not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After some research, I found out somewhere in my code `ArrayList<Type> list` is pointing to nothing(NullpointerException).

What helped me was to check if Bundle extras is `null`:

```
ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>(); // you initialize it here
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
       categories = extras.getParcelableArrayList("categories");
}
```

So if retrieved data is null it won't attach null pointer to ArrayList.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more info about *NullPointerException*